# Is there a way to confirm if data is being transmitted via a web browser to a server in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am testing out a web site that pretends to capture user login credentials.
There is a javascript in place and it verifies that data is filled or populated for credential
But I am not sure if it also transmit the data over via the script

Is there a way to check in Chrome if there is data is indeed sent over via the script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect outgoing requests in Chrome's [network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) to see whether the data you're looking for is being sent.